# dotnet image difference in dockerfile

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I m developing a worker service with .net 6.When I dockerized it I pull some images from microsot below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
```

then I can not run my worker service with `docker run` I see error below

> You must install or update .NET to run this application.
>
> App: /app/Hb.CMS.Consumer.VarnishCleaner.dll Architecture: x64
> Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64) .NET
> location: /usr/share/dotnet/
>
> No frameworks were found.
>
> Learn about framework resolution:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
>
> To install missing framework, download:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64

I changed microsoft images where in my dockerfile as below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
```

I can run my worker service with `docker run` command

So could you explain what is the difference 3 images and when I should use it in my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
```

Comment: It would be significantly easier to help you if you could provide a [mcve] - a *complete* Dockerfile, for a start, along with minimal application code and project file.

Comment: Actually I just wanted advice and suggestion about this images for usage in dockerfile @JonSkeet

Comment: You're more likely to get useful advice and suggestions if you can provide the relevant information to reproduce the issue.